# True or False: A set $(u,v,w)$ of vector is linearly independent if $u$ is not a linear combination of $v$ and $w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

A set $(u,v,w)$ of vector is linearly independent if $u$ is not a linear combination of $v$ and $w$.

It's false since if you take:
$$
\{ u = (1,0), \, 
   v = (0,1), \, 
   w = (0,0) \},
$$
this set is dependent but $u$ doesn't span $\{v, w\}$.

The part I don't get is why does $u$ not span $\{v, w\}$ and what makes the set $\{(1,0), (0,1), (0,0)\}$ dependent?

Thanks everyone

Comment: They are independent if $au+bv+cw=0\implies a=b=c=0$. In your case $0u+0v+w=0$ so $c=1$. No matter what combination you use of $v$ and $w$ you use, the first component will be $0$ so there is no way to get $(1,0)$.

Comment: w = 0 though, how did you get to 0u+0v+w = 0 ?

Comment: That's exactly why we don't need $0$ as a coefficient of $w$. If $0$ is one of your vectors, your set is always dependent.

Comment: What would U have to be in order for it to be part of the span {v,w} ?

Comment: Since $w$ doesn't contribute anything, $u$ would have to be a multiple of $v$.

Comment: I need to pay you because in just two comments, you made me understand something really important, I thank you for that !

Comment: One last thing, {1,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,2)} spans R^3  ? if not why ?

Comment: How do you know that a = 0 and b =0 and c = 1

Comment: $c$ can also be $-\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: That's not 1 though, but how do you know that a = 0 and b =0 and c = 1  ?

Comment: You still haven't answered my question